# Page suddenly scrolls back to top

Tags: scroll

So I have successfully built this business website, integrated payment gateways and I have things working just as I need them to but there's a little albeit annoying problem, when scrolling down the webpage on a mobile device, the page suddenly scrolls back up. I thought this was a problem without my chrome browser so I used other browsers still the issue persists. I currently don't know how to fix this irksome issue. Here's a [link](https://dexafxacademy.com) to the webpage. Sorry to bother you with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already fixed it, it was a problem from setting the HTML style behavior to smooth. Thank you all for your intended help!